# Get moodle current user id externally

Tags: php, moodle

my problem is simple. I'm building a plain page where I need to access some data from a moodle database, such as the current logged user ID, his messages, who sent it...

- The page is hosted locally.
- Moodle is hosted elsewhere, but I have all the required information to the database (user and password).

What I want to do, is to get the messages of the current user logged in moodle, via the cookies, or something.

I read in a few places that I can just include config.php, then get the `global $USER`, but i'd like to resort to a cookie session.

I can access the messages since I have the login informations to the database, but I need to know the current connected user, so I can retrieve his/her mails.

Is there a way to get this information without having to directly include pages from the moodle installation?

Thank you!

**edit:** to be clearer, I need to access the global `$USER` (or something containing the current logged user) outside moodle. I have access to the moodle database.

Comment: You have stated that you can access Moodle database. Can you access its files? In that case, Saad Saleem's answer is the right one.
If you can't access its files, you could create a copy of the essential ones so you can include them to create the global $USER object.
Cookies and session are going to have an ID or token of logged in user. You could try to fetch the user data from the database and write it to your own array (or $USER if you want to name it that way). But if you are going to use also other Moodle specific functions and global objects, you need to have the moodle files included.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the config.php for that purpose.

```
<?php
require_once("yourwebsite./config.php") ; //this assumes your php file is in a subdirectory of your      moodle 
require_login(); //Won't do any good to 'get' a username 'til sombody's logged in.

echo $USER->username; 
echo $USER->firstname; // and so on..

?>
```

Sources Moodle Forum: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=60634 https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=55654&parent=253937

Comment: It worked for me but only when the php page I created was inside the `moodle` subdirectory. I didn't try that hard to get it to work outside because it's not what I require.

Comment: how to use only sessions?